# Numpy not found

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, quarto

I have just recently started to use .qmd for python codes. My issue is that numpy works if I run a cell in vs code simple, but cannot be found if the notebook is to render...

I enclose a screenshot about the error. What is going wrong, and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a gentle reminder, this is **not a discussion forum** - please do not "sign off" on posts, or talk about your skill level or anything else conversation. Instead, focus on **asking** a *clear, specific* question. I [edit]ed the post to attempt to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

In general, `numpy` works when imported from Quarto, I use it frequently. This problem is likely caused by some environment configuration on your machine.

If VSCode finds a virtual environment on the directory it's running from, it will automatically load it. Therefore, my suggestion to you is:

- Change to your directory with `cd <mydir>`
- Create a new virtual environment in that directory with `python3 -m venv .venv`
- Activate the environment
- Install numpy with `python3 -m pip install numpy`
- Run VSCode `code .` from that directory
- Run preview again